# Mediation effect size

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, effect-size, mediation

I'm looking to identify the effect size in mediation studies. My supervisor has told me that I should be looking for r2 but I've noticed that many studies don't report this. For example, I have attached a publicly available paper which reports a mediation study but no r2 values. I'm wondering what data available here would provide me with the effect size? http://wei.public.iastate.edu/manuscript/perfection.pdf
Many thanks.

Comment: Please paste in whatever context is necessary to understand & answer your question.
We want this thread to remain valuable even if the link goes dead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Report standardized parameter estimates. These are analogous with some sort of effect size. That's what they do in the paper.

(You might also ask your supervisor what they actually want - people sometimes ask for an effect size because they think that things should have effect sizes, but what is meant by an effect size can be complex - and it is not always clear what an effect size would even be for some situations. I would not necessarily call a standardized parameter from an SEM an effect size - and I don't think there is a possible effect size for some of these parameters. But your supervisor probably hasn't thought about that and will be satisfied with standardized estimates.)